# How to compress QEvents without using Qt internal headers?

Tags: qt, qtcore, qt-events, qcoreapplication

Since the headers needed to iterate the posted event list in `QCoreApplication::compressEvent` are considered private, is there a way of getting equivalent functionality without depending on Qt's internal headers, but only on documented semantics of Qt?

Note that this is a *different* question that [the other one concerning signals and slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866996/how-to-compress-slot-calls-when-using-queued-connection-in-qt)!

Answer (score 1):

> Since the headers needed to iterate the posted event list in QCoreApplication::compressEvent are considered private, is there a way of getting equivalent functionality without depending on Qt's internal headers, but only on documented semantics of Qt?

AFAIK, there is not [as per my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866996/how-to-compress-slot-calls-when-using-queued-connection-in-qt/20868085#20868085).

The only API for this is internal as you write, and it can change anytime without further notice. Thereby, unless someone is writing code being part of the Qt release, this should be avoided since it can break all of a sudden for end users.

I even discussed it with 1-2 developers on IRC (peppe and suy, I think), but I think we left the topic at that point that there is no public API. This may change in the future as noted in the post.

My personal suspicion, without talking to the maintainer about it, is that it has not been a common enough use case, and hence no one has bothered just yet to get it through. I could personally live without this feature on since it has not caused me any serious defect so far, even in large scale Qt based and heavily multi-threaded softwares.

It is also quite possible that there may be technical reasons behind, and it is just my ignorance.