# Given a pyqtBoundSignal how to determine the slot?

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt, pyqt5, signals-slots

Given the signal, how can I determine the slot that a particular signal is connected to?

I am familiar with how to connect signal and slots, this is more for debugging purposes.

I am using pyqt5, python 2.7

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing as "the" slot, because a signal can be connected to multiple slots, or multiple other signals, or the same signal/slot multiple times. But in any case, there is no built-in API that can list all the current connections.

You can get a *count* of the current connections for a signal, like this:

```
    count = button.receivers(button.clicked)
```

There is also [connectNotify](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#connectNotify) and [disconnectNotify](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#disconnectNotify) - but that doesn't get you much further, because reimplementing those methods will only tell you *which* signals were connected or disconnected for the object.

The `QtTest` module has [QSignalSpy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsignalspy.html) (only available in PyQt5), which can record all the emissions of a given signal. But, again, that will only give you the arguments that were sent, rather than where they were sent to.

I suppose the reason why Qt doesn't provide an API for this is that the list of connected items is potentially very volatile.

PS:

I forgot to mention [dumpObjectInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#dumpObjectInfo), which apparently does what you're asking for, but will only work with a debug build of Qt - for release builds, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

No robust way of doing that: check out the *accepted* answer of [Determine signals connected to a given slot in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755694/determine-signals-connected-to-a-given-slot-in-qt) and the more recent answer by Kuba on that page. The conclusion is that you are better off stating what problem you are trying to solve, maybe others will have solution that does not involve determining connections.

Comment: The main problem with that accepted answer (from the point of view of this question) is that it is only relevant to PyQt4 (and even then, only if you use the old-style syntax). It could not work at all with PyQt5, because there is no `QObject.connect` (i.e. PyQt5 only supports the new-style syntax). For PyQt, there would need to be some way to hook into the mechanism by which a `pyqtBoundSignal` connects to a slot. That might be possible for custom signals, but what about all the built-in signals? I can't see a way...

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes thanks for the clarification. Although unfortunate that Qt doesn't support this, that's why I'm think the OP is better off looking for different method of debugging.