# Maintaining signal connections over instance swap Qt5

Tags: c++, interface, signals, qt5, signals-slots

In my **Qt5** program I have an **interface** with some **signals**.

An implementation of this interface is instanciated at start up and the signals are connected to from different parts of the program (many places).

Now I want to *delete* that instance and *create a new instance*, possibly from another implementation, and somehow *maintain the signal connections* so that all the places that receive the signals does not need to care that the implementation changed.

Is there any way to do this elegantly or do I have to change the architecture of program to keep control over all signal connections in one location (a lot of work)?

Example:

```
//PS: To be regarded as pseudocode at best, as lots of Qt boilerplate
//    and error handling code has been left out, and lots of bugs are left in :-)

struct MyInterface{
  virtual void doStuff()=0;
 signals:
  void someSignal();
}

struct MyImpX:public MyInterface{
  void doStuff(){
    qDebug()<<"MyImpX";
    if((random()%100)<5){
      emit someSignal();
    }
  }
}

struct MyImpY:public MyInterface{
  void doStuff(){
    qDebug()<<"MyImpY";
    if((random()%100)<10){
      emit someSignal();
    }
  }
}

struct MyWorker{
  QTimer t;
  MyInterface *inst=0;
  MyWorker(MyInterface *inst):
    inst(inst)
  {
    connect(&t,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(doStuff()));
    t.start(100);
  }
  void setNewInstance(MyInterface *inst){
    this->inst=inst;
  }
  void doStuff(){
    if(0!=inst){
      inst->doStuff();
    }
  }
}


struct MyConsumer{
  public slots:
  void handleIt(){
    qDebug()<<"Handling signal";
  }
}



void main(){
 QApplication app;
 MyInterface *inst=new MyImpX();
  MyWorker con(inst);
  MyConsumer i,j,k,l;
  //In this example all the connects are in one place, but
  //in reality they are called from several locations that
  //Are hard to control.
  connect(inst,SIGNAL(someSignal()),&i,SLOT(handleIt()));
  connect(inst,SIGNAL(someSignal()),&j,SLOT(handleIt()));
  connect(inst,SIGNAL(someSignal()),&k,SLOT(handleIt()));
  connect(inst,SIGNAL(someSignal()),&l,SLOT(handleIt()));
  //[ ... At this point some time passes where the signal is working ]
  //Now the instance changes, so the old connections are lost.
  con.setNewInstance(new MyImpY());
  delete inst;
  inst=0;
  //[ ... At this point some time passes where the signal is NOT working ]
 app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to implement something based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755694/determine-signals-connected-to-a-given-slot-in-qt), but I think that'll be hacky at best.

So, instead, you could have a proxy object, which does not get changed, and which can change its connections when the actual object changes. For this, you should probably use signal-signal connections, though you could also write slots which emit signals. Question has pseudocode, so here's some pseudocode as well, to demonstrate the principle.

```
class MyInterfaceSignalProxy : public MyInterface { 
//...
public:
    void reconnect(MyInterface *newObj, MyInterface *oldObj=0) {
        if(oldObj) disconnect(oldObj, 0, this, 0); // disconnect old connections
        connect(newObj, SIGNAL(someSignal()), this, SIGNAL(someSignal()));
    }

signals:
    void someSignal();
}
```

Of course you could remove the `oldObj` parameter, and for example store the currently connected object as private variable, or just not care about disconnection earlier connectios (for example if `oldObj` will be deleted or otherwise disconnected elsewhere).

And then your `main` would start something like:

```
void main(){
  QApplication app;

  MyInterfaceSignalProxy proxy; 
  MyConsumer i,j,k,l;
  connect(&proxy,SIGNAL(someSignal()),&i,SLOT(handleIt()));
  connect(&proxy,SIGNAL(someSignal()),&j,SLOT(handleIt()));
  connect(&proxy,SIGNAL(someSignal()),&k,SLOT(handleIt()));
  connect(&proxy,SIGNAL(someSignal()),&l,SLOT(handleIt()));

  MyInterface *inst=new MyImpX();
  proxy.reconnect(inst);
  //....

  MyInterface *inst2=new MyImpY();
  proxy.reconnect(inst2, inst);
  delete inst; // whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for an good answer! I was not aware that signal-to-signal connections was possible, that will probably prove handy. I actually solved this after realizing that the emit keyword may be used to emit signals on behalf of any object, not just "this". So in my app I put all the signals on a proxy object and connect to that and then simply do "emit proxy.signal" from wherever the signal is sent.