# Determine if a slot is connected to a given signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I'm interested to know if there is some way that I can determine that there is a connection to a given signal that I've defined in a class. It's basically a signal to process data, and I don't care what it's connected to, but I'd like to include a sanity check that I'm not sending data into the void where it will never be seen. I've checked out [Determine signals connected to a given slot in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755694/determine-signals-connected-to-a-given-slot-in-qt), but it's kind of the opposite problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is `QObject::isSignalConnected()` for exactly that usecase - avoiding unnecessary work to prepare a signal emission when no one is listening. Its [API docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#isSignalConnected) even come with a nice example.

**Example:**

```
static const QMetaMethod valueChangedSignal = QMetaMethod::fromSignal(&MyObject::valueChanged);
if (isSignalConnected(valueChangedSignal)) {
    QByteArray data;
    data = get_the_value();       // expensive operation
    emit valueChanged(data);
}
```

Comment: can't believe I missed that.

Comment: This did not work for me when an `QObject` was destroyed, while `receivers(SIGNAL(finished())` did work

Comment: Qt 5.15.0 QObject::isSignalConnected always returns false?